# In a constructor can I take the address of members and rely that they will remain unchanged?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this line of code:

```
boneHierarchy = BoneHierarchy(Point3D(24.5f,
                                       84.0f + HumanBoundingBox::HEIGHT/2.0f ,24.5f
                                      ),
                              CompassRadians(0.0f),
                              renderingEngine
                             );
```

BoneHierarchy has some vectors as private members.  I take the address of the vectors and pass them to a rendering class.  But I'm getting garbage when the when I call the size member function of the vector.  I am taking the address of the vectors and not the elements in it.

```
BoneHierarchy::BoneHierarchy(Point3D const& position,
                             CompassRadians const& heading,
                             Renderer* renderingEngine) : counter(0), renderingEngine(renderingEngine)
{    




    CoordinateSystem bodyCoordSys = CoordinateSystem(
                                                     Vector3D(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
                                                     Vector3D(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));


    map<Normal3D::enumeration, TextureCoordinates> cubeTextureKind;
    Normal3D::enumeration normal;
    for (normal = Normal3D::begin(); normal != Normal3D::end(); ++normal)
    {
        cubeTextureKind[normal] = TextureAtlas::textureAtlasCoordLookup(WOOD);
    }
    Bone body = Bone(
                     Vector3D(0.0f, HumanBoundingBox::HEIGHT/2.0f,0.0f),
                     HumanBoundingBox::DIM,
                     Euler3D(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),
                     cubeTextureKind,
                     bodyCoordSys);
    //TODO there are two positions for the human, one here and one in mesh vbo, unify these into one.
    body.setPosition(Vector3D(position.getX(),position.getY(),position.getZ()));
    body.setEuler(Euler3D((float) (Math::toDegrees(heading.getValue())),0.0f,0.0f));
    drawBone(body,UPDATE_ALL);
    root = body;


    map<string,Renderer::Buffer> vboVariableMap;
    vboVariableMap["aVertexPosition"] = Renderer::Buffer(verticesBuf);
    vboVariableMap["aTextureCoord"] = Renderer::Buffer(texCoordsBuf);
    vboVariableMap["index"] = Renderer::Buffer(indicesBuf);
    cout << "aBoneIndex " << boneIndexBuf.size() << endl;
    vboVariableMap["aBoneIndex"] = Renderer::Buffer(boneIndexBuf);
    vboVariableMap["uBoneMatrix0"] = Renderer::Buffer(transformMatrixBuf);
    GLuint textureID = 0; 
    Renderer::VBODescription vboDescription = Renderer::VBODescription("boneShader",
                                                                       vboVariableMap,
                                                                       GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW,
                                                                       indicesBuf.size(),
                                                                       textureID);
    bufferID = renderingEngine->registerBuffer(vboDescription);
    cout << "bufferID " << bufferID << endl;
    renderingEngine->printBoneIndexSize();
    cout << &(getBoneIndexBuf()) << endl;
}


Renderer::Buffer::Buffer(vector<GLfloat> const& data):
floatData(&data), ushortData(NULL), target(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)
{
    printf("pointer: %p, size: %lu\n", floatData, floatData->size());
}

Renderer::Buffer::Buffer(vector<GLushort> const& data):
floatData(NULL), ushortData(&data), target(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)
{
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you take the address?

Comment: I second @dasblinkenlight. As an aside, passing pointers are dangerous because it depends on the provider of the pointer to not invalidate the pointer by destroying the vector. This is especially true if the pointer is being held for a time before use.

Comment: I added the code in the constructor and showed the Buffer constructor as well which copies the pointer over from the reference passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `BoneHierarchy` constructor that accepts a `Point3D` and a `CompassRadians` computes the addresses of its own vector members, that's fine. Their addresses won't change.

The code also shows an assignment statement. The addresses of the vector members of the temporary `BoneHierarchy` on the right will be different from those of the `BoneHierarchy` object stored in `boneHierarchy` on the left. Make sure you're not copying the addresses in your assignment operator, or else the `boneHierarchy` object will end up referring to the vector members of a temporary object that doesn't exist anymore. You'll also want to check your copy constructor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what is burning me.  I'm passing pointers to members in the constructor and then when the data gets copied/assigned the addresses end up being different.  Is there a good way of fixing this?

Comment: Yes. Write a copy constructor and assignment operator so they don't copy the pointers from the original object. Better yet, don't bother *storing* the vector pointers at all. The object can easily re-compute the addresses of its members at any time with the `&` operator, so there's no reason for it to store copies of them.

Answer (score 0):

Their addresses will not change. In addition, if you are not in the initializer list, their contents should be valid all throughout construction.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough code provided here. 
Assuming that you only wanted to create an instance,
use this line of code instead:

```
 BoneHierarchy boneHierarchy(Point3D(24.5f, 84.0f + HumanBoundingBox::HEIGHT/2.0f ,24.5f), 
 CompassRadians(0.0f), renderingEngine);
```

This would create an instance in the local stack. As rob pointed out, you must be invoking the assignment operator to BoneHierarchy.